# ASP.NET localization--where are the international resource strings?

Tags: asp.net, localization

I just started working on a new International project. All strings in the markup of ASPX pages are instead System.Web.UI.WebControls.Localize controls with "meta:resourcekey=" attributes. In the web root there's a App_LocalResources and in a App_GlobalResources, but the strings in all resource files are all English.

Where is the web site getting the International language-strings? Is there some built-in translator for ASP.NET? Where should I look to see the unicode foreign language characters?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in translator.

You should see resource files for each .aspx page in the App_LocalResources folder.  For each .aspx file, there will be multiple resources files, one for each translation, with different file names like:

```
AddCustomer.aspx.resx
AddCustomer.aspx.fr.resx
AddCustomer.aspx.en-US.resx
```

etc. etc.  Each file contains the translation for the culture given in the filename.

Comment: If you don't see the files, make sure "Show all files" is enabled. Maybe they're on the disk but not in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a Page or User Control open in design view there's an option to localize off the Tools menu (I think). That'll create an App_LocalResources folder in whatever folder your currently working in. The App_LocalResources in the root will be for pages in the root of the website. App_GlobalResources is for your web.sitemap and any other resources you wish to use throughout the entire site.

I set up sub folders within App_LocalResources for each language.

For example, some pages:

Default.aspx
Create.aspx
View.aspx

-> App_LocalResources // folder

Default.aspx.resx // default language is picked up if browser's preferences not satisfied.
Create.aspx.resx
View.aspx.resx

--> DE// sub folder for german

Default.aspx.de.resx
Create.aspx.de.resx
View.aspx.de.resx

--> FR// sub folder for french

Default.aspx.fr.resx
Create.aspx.fr.resx
View.aspx.fr.resx

I've never had to do anything to specify a particular country's brand of a language (outside of displaying currenceis that is) but if you needed Austrian German say then you could do this.

--> DE-AT// sub folder for Austrian german

Default.aspx.de-AT.resx
Create.aspx.de-AT.resx
View.aspx.de-AT.resx

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible that a custom resource provider has been created (this is the best thing to do when dealing with a largish site/program). There's an [overview of resource providers here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx) which might help you track down what's happen if the resx files are genuinely nowhere to be found.